# Php actionscript bitMapData post image

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I would like to be able to display an image on the file script.php with the help of data transmitted by this code (Actionscript)

I get data by the POST method but I do not know what to do with it.

---

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

I don't know what to do with $_POST

---

```
 public function onTakePhoto(param1:Event) : void
{
  var _loc1_:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(680,440));
  var _loc2_:Matrix = new Matrix();
  _loc2_.translate(-290,-150);
  _loc2_.scale(2,2);
  _loc1_.bitmapData.draw(DisplayObject(something),_loc2_);

  var _loc3_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
  _loc1_.bitmapData.encode(_loc1_.bitmapData.rect,new JPEGEncoderOptions(),_loc3_);

  var _loc4_:URLRequest = new URLRequest("script.php");
  _loc4_.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
  _loc4_.data = _loc3_;

  navigateToURL(_loc4_,"_blank");
  _loc1_.bitmapData.dispose();
}
```

Comment: The provided script is a result of decompilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the $_POST data like this:

```
$image_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

//proceed by perhaps saving the image to the server:
file_put_contents('path/to/save/image.jpg',$image_data);
```